# Implicit broadcast receiver on Android O

Tags: broadcast, android-8.0-oreo

I wanted to create broadcast receiver to listen battery level changes even if my application is in background. On android Oreo 8.0 implicit broadcast is not working and I can't use JobScheduler as it is supporting api level 21+(Need to support api level 19). How can I solve this issue?